# styling SVG groups using CSS classes

Tags: css, svg

I would like to highlight SVG groups using CSS. I have tried the following code

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <style type="text/css">
    * {stroke: black; fill: white}
    .A:hover {fill: orange}
    .B:hover {fill: blue}
  </style>
  <g class="A">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" />
    <circle cx="250" cy="100" r="50" />
  </g>
  <circle class="B" cx="400" cy="100" r="50" />
</svg>
```

but the first two circles do not turn orange upon hover (in Safari and Opera). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add style in the header, not the body....

Comment: @arpit: Semicolons are not necessary there. Bondye: the style is fine like this, there's no <head> or <body> in svg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fill will get set on the hovered `<g>`, but the other selector overrides the fill on the circles.

Replace:

```
.A:hover {fill: orange}
```

With:

```
.A:hover * {fill: orange}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nuw82/).